# How to Select the rows where i found one times the customer id

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to do a request to my table where I select the rows where I found one times the customer id

My table structure looks like this:

```
id , date_commande, id_customer
```

I don't want to return the lines if I found customer id twice or more

example of data:

```
id  | date_commande | id_customer
--------------------------------
01  |   2011-12-01  |     10
02  |   2011-12-01  |     11
03  |   2011-12-02  |     14
04  |   2011-12-03  |     10
```

I want just return the line

```
id  | date_commande | id_customer
--------------------------------
02  |   2011-12-01  |     11
03  |   2011-12-02  |     14
```

Comment: can you provide some sample data and your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slightly improved version of the query that @Florin suggested..

```
Select ID, date_commande, ID_customer
from table
where ID_Customer in
(Select ID_Customer from table Group by ID_Customer having count(*) = 1)
```

Comment: Agrees w/ Robert's added comment: and gave a +1 to florin.

Answer (score 4):

```
select * 
from table 
where id_customer in 
 (select id_customer 
  from table 
  group by id_customer 
  having count(*) = 1)
```

Comment: I was also sure "having count(*) = 1" would work, but maybe it's a Version thing.

Comment: All I can think is that there was an implementation problem, thus the explicit naming instead of * on the top select.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for even more feedback, here is the again revised version

```
SELECT id, date_commande,id_customer
FROM (
  SELECT
    MIN(id) as id, 
    MIN(date_commande) as date_commande,
    MIN(id_customer) as id_customer,
    COUNT(*) as numrows
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY id_customer
)
WHERE numrows=1
```

Comment: still need improvement :) not a group by expression

Comment: @FlorinGhita Thanks, I would have thought to have used that many times, but seems this was never with Oracle. Revised my SQL.

Comment: @FlorinGhita - can you elaborate which improvement?

Comment: the columns that aren't in the group by can be selected only with aggregate functions.

Comment: id_customer  invalid identifier ??

Comment: @FlorinGhita thanks again, Oracle really is a very silly database! Revised again. Mercer: Ther was a typo with id_customer mistyped to id_cutsomer, I fixed it